# session.get() returning null in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, session

Im working with hibernate and mysql, and i got it working to put data in the DB via hibernate, but when i try to retrieve data it always returns null...

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
User user = (User) session.get(User.class, username);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

User is a class with annotations, but the variable user will always be null, even if i put a username that i know exists in the DB. Username is the ID of the table, so it should find it

**EDIT**

Can it be that i use `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` in the config? What should i use so the DB create the table only if it does not exist?

Comment: what is the SQL being generated at the time of `session.get()` do you have `hibernate.show.sql` set to true

Comment: Thanks, when i put it in and i get:

Hibernate: drop table if exists user
Hibernate: create table user (username varchar(255) not null, age integer, name varchar(255), password varchar(255), sex varchar(255), surname varchar(255), primary key (username))

when it does this: Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

Thus it is recreating the table :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the create schema option will delete all the existing data!**
Check out the documentation : [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-misc-properties)

Following are the specified options:

- `validate`: validate the schema, However no changes are made to the database.
- `update`: update the schema.
- **`create`**: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
- `create-drop`: drop the schema at the end of the session.

Try using the `update` version. The rest of the code snippet looks fine to me.

Hope this helps

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-question-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do which was asked along the same lines.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
Is it an good idea using this method for serious development and deployment?